# What is the best Mongodb Sharding key for my schema?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am design a Mongodb collection which can save the statistic for daily volume

Here is my DB schema

```
mongos> db.arq.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553b78637e6962c36d67c728"),
    "ip" : NumberLong(635860665),
    "ts" : ISODate("2015-04-25T00:00:00Z"),
    "values" : {
        "07" : 2,
        "12" : 1
    },
    "daily_ct" : 5
}
mongos>
```

And Here is my Indexes

```
mongos> db.arq.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "Query_Volume.test"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "ip" : 1
        },
        "name" : "ip_1",
        "ns" : "Query_Volume.test"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "ts" : 1
        },
        "name" : "ts_1",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 15552000,
        "ns" : "Query_Volume.test"
    }
]
mongos>
```

Note: I have a time stamp index since I need to use TTL mechanism.

But the Sharding Key has any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1. `{ts: 1}` Your timestamp. The data of certain ranges will be located together, but the key is monotonically increasing, and I'm not sure, whether the TTL index will clean up shard chunks. Means: The write load switches from shard to shard, and you have a shard with high write load whereas the other shards will get no writes for the data. This pattern works nicely if you query contiguous time ranges but has downsides in writing.
2. `{ts: "hashed"}` Hash-based sharding. The data will be sharded more or less evenly across the shards. Hash-based sharding distributes the write load but involves **all** shards (more or less) when querying for data.

You will need to test, what fits the best for your reads and writes. The sharding key depends on the data structure and the read/write patterns of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
But how about both in "ip" and "ts". Since in our query scenario more likely
    db.col.find({"ip":some_ip, "ts":{"$gte":ts1, "$lte":ts2}})

Comment: Then go for {ip:1, ts:1}, if this is your most issued query. If the keyspace for ip is small, it's going to be extended by the timestamp.